# How to change class object parameters from another module (python)

Tags: python, class, import, module, attributes

So I've searched around and couldn't find an answer. I'm looking to change parameters from an object created in my main file, in a module. For example, I'm testing this with a simple piece of code here:

-this is my main file, from which i create the objects and define some properties

```
import class_test_2

class dog():
    name=''
    spots=0

    def add_spots(self):
        self.spots+=1

def main():

    fido=dog()
    fido.name='Fido'

    print('Fido\'s spots: ',fido.spots)

    fido.add_spots()

    print('Fido\'s spots: ',fido.spots)

    class_test_2.class_test()

    print('Fido\'s spots: ',fido.spots)


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

---

-this is the module, from which I want to use functions to change the attributes in the main file

```
from class_test_1 import dog

def class_test():
    fido.add_spots()
```

-So my question is how can I do this/why doesn't this piece of code above work? 
Running the main function on its own shows fido's spots increasing by 1 each time its printed. Running the code calling the module however gives a NameError so my module isn't recognising the class exists even though I've managed to import it. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why do you think importing `dog` gives you access to `fido`? That's defined only in `main` which doesn't even run on import. Also, do you know they're class not instance attributes? And why the circular imports?

Comment: So is there no way I can import an object with its properties intact at any point in time? Say in the middle of my main function I want to check the value of a variable tied to an object, but I want to do that checking from a module. I just want to save space in my main function really...

Comment: Certainly not using import. Pass explicitly, it's much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable "fido" is only defined within your "main" function.  You must provide your "class_test" function with the variable.

For example:

```
 class_test_2.class_test(fido)
```

Then your `class_test` function gets an argument.  You can choose the name freely.  I used `the_dog` in the example:

```
def class_test(the_dog):
    the_dog.add_spots()
```

In this case `the_dog` points to the same instance of your `dog` class as `fido`.